# Opentelemetry OtlpGrpcSpanExporter class found

Tags: java, spring-boot, open-telemetry

Below is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mypackage</groupId>
  <artifactId>myid</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <camunda.version>7.8.0</camunda.version>
    <!-- Build properties -->
    <maven.version>3.0.0</maven.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
          <artifactId>opentelemetry-bom</artifactId>
          <version>1.28.0</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>7.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>
      <version>7.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.spin</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-spin-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.spin</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-spin-dataformat-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.spin</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-spin-dataformat-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.camunda.commons/camunda-commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.everit.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- database -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-assert</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
      <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-common</artifactId>
      <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <layout>ZIP</layout>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>17</source>
          <target>17</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And I have `OtlpExporterConfig.java` like below:

```
package com.mypackage.configurations;

import io.opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.trace.OtlpGrpcSpanExporter;
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export.SpanExporter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class OtlpExporterConfig {

    @Value("${opentelemetry.trace.exporter.otlp.endpoint}")
    private String otlpEndpoint;

    @Bean
    public SpanExporter otlpSpanExporter() {
        return OtlpGrpcSpanExporter.builder()
                .setEndpoint(otlpEndpoint)
                .build();
    }
}
```

But OtlpGrpcSpanExporter is not found. In my intellij IDE, I can also spot exporter is not available under io.opentelemetry. Can someone please spot the problem , as to, why import is not working

Comment: try `mvn dependency:tree` to confirm the expected dependency versions. also you could try Intellij > Maven > Reload project.